# Kendo Grid - Customize Filter Row

Tags: telerik, kendo-grid

there is a feature called "Filter Row" in Kendo Grid

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-row

I want to add a drop-down list instead of a text box or a number box, to the filter box. It's for filtering a column that has countries. So I want list of countries in a drop-down list. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm trying to do this as well. So far I've gotten to the point where I have my filter drop down but it's resetting to 0 after selecting a value and the filter request sent to the ajax request is empty.

Answer (score 7):

It's very similar to the custom Filter Menu (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-menu-customization). I made the mistake of no using `valuePrimitive: true`. You might not want it in your situation but keep that in mind.

Here's a sample: http://dojo.telerik.com/OKaS

Also, the filter menu should take up the editor model of the column but it's not always what you want.

**Edit**

Starting from 2014 Q2 SP1, the template function now receives an object containing "datasource" and "element". In my example, you would have to change the dropdown initialization from "container.kendoDropDownList" to "container.element.kendoDropDownList". The datasource is empty in my example but I'm assuming this can be used to pass the choices to a control without requiring another datasource or to externalize your current.  I have not experimented with this feature but I suggest you do before taking my sample blindly.

Comment: I don't get how this works for you. When I try to call a function as a template, I get error that `.kendoDropDownList` is undefined for `container`. If I bind function to `ui`, it doesn't even see argument, although there is no error. Either way I can't get this to work, except setting `.kendoDropDownList` to html element on `document.ready`, which works but is ugly.

Comment: Why was my answer downvoted? @MarkoStanojevic Can you post a sample of what you have tried? My example works so unless I know what you did differently, there's nothing more I can say.

Comment: OK, I posted how I tried to do it. Please let me know if you see something wrong. If not, I guess I need to expand the samples. As in your example, same scripts are included, namely `kendo.all.min.js` and `angular.min.js`. Thank you.

Comment: This certainly did not deserve a down vote. The example works and the explanation is clear. I had the same issue as the asker and thanks to Pluc I was able to sort it out. The edit which explains to use container.element is what fixed it up for me. This should also be marked as the answer, since if it still isn't working for you then you most likely have a configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

As Pluc mentioned earlier `valuePrimitive: true` will help you create a custom filter for your grid/columns to send id's to your controller, if you are not using setting this property true you will receive an Object in your controller instead of a number, the conversion will not be made automatically . This is still working as of 2019